# RunTime Error while Lazy Loading a module

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

While lazy-loading a component separately, I'm getting the following run-time error. I'm using Angular 6. The issue is while I write `loadChildren` into routing module of another component, this is the error which occurs. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Component 1's routing module:

    {
      path: 'componentTwo',
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     loadChildren:'../component/component.module#ComponentTwoModule'
    }
```

**Error Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: The error seems to tell you that you are trying to call a function which does not exist or is undefined. But without any code provided of what you are trying to do, it will be nearly impossible to tell you what you are doing wrong and how to solve it.

Comment: @mrdeadsven I am actually trying to separate the routing of two modules. i.e. Component 2's routing module is included in Component 1's routing module.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like error in your component or module that you injected